# Summing up the outer elements in a 2D array of integers in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

One of the questions from my exam asked to write some code to compute the sum of the outer int elements of a 2D array. Length of rows and length of columns aren't necessarily equal.

[EDIT] Corner values cannot be added more than once.

I came up with this code and it works, but I'd like to know if there are more efficient ways to achieve the same results. Thanks.

`for(int i = 0; i < in.length; i ++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < in[i].length; j++) {
                if(i == 0 || i == in.length - 1) {
                    sum += in[i][j];
                }
                else {
                    sum += in[i][in[i].length - 1 ] + in[i][0];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: It's O(n + m) no matter what, where n = number of rows and m = number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, then you could first extract a method to add the elements of one array like

```
public static int sumArray(int[] in) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int val : in) {
        sum += val;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Then you can add the elements on the first and last rows like

```
int sum = sumArray(in[0]) + sumArray(in[in.length - 1]);
```

And then the outer elements from the other rows with an additional (non-nested) loop like

```
for (int i = 1; i < in.length - 1; i++) {
    sum += in[i][0] + in[i][in[i].length - 1];
}
```

**Or**, in Java 8+, you might eliminate the extra method and the explicit loop and do it with one statement like

```
int sum = IntStream.of(in[0]).sum() //
        + IntStream.of(in[in.length - 1]).sum() //
        + IntStream.range(1, in.length - 1).map(i -> {
            return in[i][0] + in[i][in[i].length - 1];
        }).sum();
```

Comment: The question is to get the sum of outer elements of array. You used one dimensional array only.

Comment: I add the first row, the last row and the first and last value from every row in between (every 2d array is composed of 1d arrays; *literally* an array of arrays).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it more efficiently.

```
int row = in.length;
int column = in[0].length;//not sure of this syntax but trying to get the column size
int sum = 0;

for(int j=0;j<column;j++)
{
    sum+=in[0][j]+in[row-1][j];
}
for(int j=1;j<row-1;j++)
{
    sum+=in[j][0]+in[j][column-1];
}
```

Your solution is O(mn) and the loop iterates through unnecessary indexes.

Comment: you are over counting. The corners are being counted twice.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Made the change.